# ActiveRecordのvalidations、uniqunessで条件の付け方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ActiveRecord::Baseのvalidationsで
uniqunessで複数のカラムを選択し、
さらにそのカラムの値も条件に加えることは可能でしょうか？

uniqunessの条件にしたい項目
- user_id
- mst_category_id
- でさらにactive=true

こんな感じかなって思ったのですが、全然違いました。。。

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :user_id,
             uniqueness: {
                scope: [:mst_category_id, active: true]
             }

Answer (score 1):

ためしてませんが、リファレンスによると

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :mst_category_id }, conditions: -> { where(active: true) }
```

という書き方(`conditions`)があるようです。